# Sed Editor single check

Tags: sed

I have a sed command which will append a string on the end of a line. When I re-run the same command again the same content is getting append at the end of the line again and again.

I am looking for a command which will check if the content is already there or not then proceed.

Here is my sed command:

```
shell: sed -i '/only_from/s/$/ xx.xx.xx.xx\/24/' file.txt
```

Comment: awk may be a more appropriate tool for your task

Answer (score 1):

this line works for your needs:

```
sed -i '/only_from/{/ xx\.xx\.xx\.xx\/24$/!s#$# xx.xx.xx.xx/24#}' file
```

E.g:

```
kent$  cat f
only_from foo bar

kent$  sed -i '/only_from/{/xx\.xx\.xx\.xx\/24$/!s#$# xx.xx.xx.xx/24#}' f

kent$  cat f
only_from foo bar  xx.xx.xx.xx/24

kent$  sed -i '/only_from/{/xx\.xx\.xx\.xx\/24$/!s#$# xx.xx.xx.xx/24#}' f

kent$  cat f
only_from foo bar  xx.xx.xx.xx/24
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed '/only_from/{ / xx\.xx\.xx\.xx\/24/ !s/$/ xx\.xx\.xx\.xx\/24/}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit naive, but why don't you write something as simple as

```
sed -i '/only_from$/s/$/ xx.xx.xx.xx\/24/' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But my requirement is to write for many files. So If i get the write command, i can put that in an ansible play to update in all the hosts. This command below mentioned worked well as expected.     sed -i '/only_from/{/xx\.xx\.xx\.xx\/24$/!s#$# xx.xx.xx.xx/24#}' f

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize you were expecting further information after only_from as you didn't provide an example of your input. I already upvoted Kent's answer.